# Union of Sets using Dynamic Memory

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, operator-overloading

Below I have a block of code. I am trying to create a union method for sets and it is supposed to invoke the element(int) method to check all of the elements in the new set that I am creating, which I have called C here. We are not supposed to use the union from set in the standard library. When I call A.Union(B) in the main function, and then I display it, the program is only displaying whatever I inputted into Set A, but it is supposed to return all the contents of the new set I have created in my union function. How can I get this function to return all the contents of the new set I have created, while also checking the elements to ensure that no elements are repeated??

*side note: I am fully aware of my variable names, I will change them once I understand how to correct this method. I am also a beginner, who is really trying to learn, so I would appreciate constructive criticism so I can know how to improve. 
//default constructor

```
Set::Set ( int s ){

        if ( s > 0 )
                psize = s;
        else
                psize = DEFAULTSIZE;
        //allocate an array of specified size
        set = new int[ psize ];

        if(!set) {
                //send an error is system cannot allocate memory
                cout << "Cannot Allocate Memory, exiting program... " << endl;
                exit (1);
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < psize; i++){
                set[i] = 0;
                numOfElements = 0;
        }
}
bool Set::element ( int n ){
                 for ( int i = 0; i < psize; i++){
                            if ( set[i] == n )
                                    return true;
                    }
                    return false;
            }

         Set Set::Union( Set &B ){
                int newsize = B.numOfElements + numOfElements;

                Set C(newsize);

                for (int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++){
                        C.set[i] = set[i];
                }

                int indx = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < B.numOfElements; i ++){
                        if(C.element(B.set[i])){
                                newsize--;
                                continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                C.set[indx + numOfElements] = B.set[i];
                                indx++;
                        }
                }

                C.numOfElements = newsize;
                C.display();
                return (C);
        }
        Set Set::Intersection( Set &B ) {

                int newsize = numOfElements;

                Set C(newsize);
                        for ( int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++ ){
                                if( element(B.set[i]))
                                        C.set[i] = B.set[i];
                                else{
                                        newsize--;
                                        continue;
                                }
                        }
                return (C);
        }
   Set Set::operator-( int n ){
            for ( int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++){
                    if(element(n)){
                            delete set[i];
                            numOfElements--;
                    }
            }
            psize = numOfElements;

            return (*this);
    }


            main (){

                    Set A, B, C;
                    A.input();
                    A.display();
                    B.input();
                    B.display();
                    C = A.Union(B);
                    C.display();
            }
```

Comment: Could you please share the `struct` or the `class` where you declared the data members and their functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, and this alone should solve the immediate problem, your `Union` method appears like it should provide the correct result, but it *returns* a new set. So if you want to use it properly, you want to do something like:

```
C = A.Union(B);
C.display();
```

... or more tersely:

```
A.Union(B).display();
```

When you write:

```
A.Union(B);
```

... you're computing the union, the function returns the value, but you don't capture it and so it just gets thrown away and the code basically does nothing at all (in terms of side effects).

Also just another little thing, and it won't impact correctness:

```
bool Set::element ( int n ) {
        bool validate = true;
        for ( int i = 0; i < psize; i++){
                if ( set[i] == n )
                        validate = false;
        }
        return (validate);
}
```

... this part can simply be:

```
bool Set::element ( int n ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < psize; i++){
                if ( set[i] == n )
                        return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

It's quite a bit more efficient since it'll exit the function the moment it finds a match, and won't continue to needlessly search the rest of the set when it has already found a match.

More importantly though, dealing with state is hard. The more variables you have in your functions, typically the more error-prone things get. So if you can see how to avoid it, try not to introduce more variables than needed and it'll tend to make your life easier.

It might be a little easier to understand this `element` function if it returned true on finding an element rather than false, but that's up to you.

Last but not least, I strongly recommend learning the debugger for whatever compiler you have at the moment. If you want something resembling a legal "cheat" that will give you an edge over other students and let you become in touch with what your code is doing at every little step and what's wrong with it, learn the debugger and learn how to trace through your code and see the values of the variables at any given time. With understanding of the debugger, a lot of these issues will become immediately obvious to you, and without scratching your head and staring at the code until you become cross-eyed (though this is also sometimes a useful exercise).

Comment: I hope this doesn't sound like a dumb question, but where can I find the debugger? Furthermore, where can I go to learn how to use the debugger?

Comment: What do you compile your code against? GCC? MSVC? Clang? Something else? Do you use an IDE or just like a plain old text editor?

Comment: I'm guessing you use GCC (most likely) in that case. If that's the case, GDB is your debugger -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xQ0ONbt-qPs

Comment: I have edited my code based on your suggestions, but there is something i am still not understanding because it is still returning the contents of Set A

Comment: Hmm -- the logic in your `Union` method appears to be sound. I've double-checked and triple-checked and cannot find anything wrong with it (though I do keep stumbling over that part where `element` returns false when an element is found rather than true). I would check some of the code you haven't shown yet, like your copy constructor which would get invoked when returning `C` from `Union`.

Comment: Some other tips before you go full-fledged with using the debugger -- sprinkle testing code into your routines. For example, try calling `C.Display();` from inside `Set::Union` (right before you return it). Get to the bottom of the issue that way by printing things out in the middle of what you are doing, and you can get some pseudo-debugging that way -- let the computer show you the data in the middle stages so you can get to the bottom of what's happening through a process of elimination. Debugging code is kind of like playing investigator and eliminating possible suspects.

Comment: After you figure out what's wrong, you can remove all the test code -- but it's useful to add lots of it as you're working, especially when you're just learning how to do things and figuring things out as you go.

Answer (score 1):

`Set::element` returns `false` if `n` equals the last element of the set. Otherwise it returns `true`. That's probably not what you intended.

Also `newsize` should be `B.psize + psize` only if you add all elements from both sets. But if some elements are in both `A` and `B`, then you wouldn't add all of them.

Also, `main` function lacks the return type.

> When I call A.Union(B) in the main function, and then I display it, the program is only displaying whatever I inputted into Set A

But you never display `A.Union(B)`. After the union, you call `A.display()`. Not at all surprising that it displays what you *inputted into Set A*. You never even store the set returned by `Set::Union` in a variable.

Comment: I think that union loop actually does make sense albeit really oddly written. The code is just using an array-based rep, linear searches for everything, and with possible gaps in between. That loop's logic reads as like, "for each additional entry in C: for each entry in B: if the B entry is not found in C, set C entry to B entry (basically add it)." It's really confusing with the superfluous continue and `element` returning false instead of true when something is found.

Comment: @Ike fair enough, I shall remove that comment.